# Javascript Game following the player

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to get a enemy to follow my player in my Javascript game. i have tried googling but am coming up short. 
i want any of the oponents to follow the player around where ever it goes.
here is my code so please help.

```
var simpleLevelPlan = [
  "                      ",
  "                      ",
  "  x              = x  ",
  "  x         o o    x  ",
  "  x @      xxxxx   x  ",
  "  xxxxx            x  ",
  "      x!!!!!!!!!!!!x  ",
  "      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  ",
  "                      "
];

function Level(plan) {
  this.width = plan[0].length;
  this.height = plan.length;
  this.grid = [];
  this.actors = [];

  for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
    var line = plan[y], gridLine = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
      var ch = line[x], fieldType = null;
      var Actor = actorChars[ch];
      if (Actor)
        this.actors.push(new Actor(new Vector(x, y), ch));
      else if (ch == "x")
        fieldType = "wall";
      else if (ch == "q")
        fieldType = "animal";
      else if (ch == "!")
        fieldType = "lava";
      else if (ch == "s")
        fieldType = "spike";

      gridLine.push(fieldType);
    }
    this.grid.push(gridLine);
  }

  this.player = this.actors.filter(function(actor) {
    return actor.type == "player";
  })[0];
  this.status = this.finishDelay = null;
}

Level.prototype.isFinished = function() {
  return this.status !== null && this.finishDelay < 0;
};

function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x; this.y = y;
}
Vector.prototype.plus = function(other) {
  return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
};
Vector.prototype.times = function(factor) {
  return new Vector(this.x * factor, this.y * factor);
};

var actorChars = {
  "@": Player,
  "o": Coin,
  "w": Chest,
  "s": Spike,
  "q": Animal,
  "=": Lava, "|": Lava, "v": Lava
};

function Player(pos) {
  this.pos = pos.plus(new Vector(0, -0.5));
  this.size = new Vector(0.8, 1.5);
  this.speed = new Vector(0, 0);
  this.height = new Vector(1, 1);
}
Player.prototype.type = "player";

function Lava(pos, ch) {
  this.pos = pos;
  this.size = new Vector(1, 1);
  if (ch == "=") {
    this.speed = new Vector(2, 0);
  } else if (ch == "|") {
    this.speed = new Vector(0, 2);
  } else if (ch == "v") {
   this.speed = new Vector(0, 3);
    this.repeatPos = pos;
  }

};


Lava.prototype.type = "lava";

function Spike(pos, ch) {
  this.pos = pos;
  this.size = new Vector(1, 1);
    if (ch == "s") {
    this.speed = new Vector(0, 3);
    this.repeatPos = pos;
  }
}
Spike.prototype.type = "spike";

function Coin(pos) {
  this.basePos = this.pos = pos.plus(new Vector(0.2, 0.1));
  this.size = new Vector(0.6, 0.6);
  this.wobble = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
}
Coin.prototype.type = "coin";

function Chest(pos) {
  this.basePos = this.pos = pos.plus(new Vector(0.2, 0.1));
  this.size = new Vector(1, 1);
  this.wobble = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
}
Chest.prototype.type = "chest";

var simpleLevel = new Level(simpleLevelPlan);

function elt(className) {
  if (className) elt.className = className;
  return elt;
}        
function Animal(pos, ch) {
  this.pos = pos;
  this.size = new Vector(1, 1);
  if (ch == "q") {
    this.speed = new Vector(2, 0);
  } 
}

Animal.prototype.type = "animal";



function DOMDisplay(parent, level) {
  this.wrap = parent.appendChild(elt("div", "game"));
  this.level = level;

  this.wrap.appendChild(this.drawBackground());
  this.actorLayer = null;
  this.drawFrame();
}

var scale = 40;

DOMDisplay.prototype.drawBackground = function() {
  var table = elt("table", "background");
  table.style.width = this.level.width * scale + "px";
  this.level.grid.forEach(function(row) {
    var rowElt = table.appendChild(elt("tr"));
    rowElt.style.height = scale + "px";
    row.forEach(function(type) {
      rowElt.appendChild(elt("td", type));
    });
  });
  return table;
};

DOMDisplay.prototype.drawActors = function() {
  var wrap = elt("div");
  this.level.actors.forEach(function(actor) {
    var rect = wrap.appendChild(elt("div",
                                    "actor " + actor.type));
    rect.style.width = actor.size.x * scale + "px";
    rect.style.height = actor.size.y * scale + "px";
    rect.style.left = actor.pos.x * scale + "px";
    rect.style.top = actor.pos.y * scale + "px";
  });
  return wrap;
};

    DOMDisplay.prototype.drawFrame = function() {
  if (this.actorLayer)
    this.wrap.removeChild(this.actorLayer);
  this.actorLayer = this.wrap.appendChild(this.drawActors());
  this.wrap.className = "game " + (this.level.status || "");
  this.scrollPlayerIntoView();
};

DOMDisplay.prototype.scrollPlayerIntoView = function() {
  var width = this.wrap.clientWidth;
  var height = this.wrap.clientHeight;
  var margin = width / 3;

 // The viewport
  var left = this.wrap.scrollLeft, right = left + width;
  var top = this.wrap.scrollTop, bottom = top + height;

  var player = this.level.player;
  var center = player.pos.plus(player.size.times(0.5))
                 .times(scale);

  if (center.x < left + margin)
    this.wrap.scrollLeft = center.x - margin;
  else if (center.x > right - margin)
    this.wrap.scrollLeft = center.x + margin - width;
  if (center.y < top + margin)
    this.wrap.scrollTop = center.y - margin;
  else if (center.y > bottom - margin)
    this.wrap.scrollTop = center.y + margin - height;
};

DOMDisplay.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.wrap.parentNode.removeChild(this.wrap);
};

Level.prototype.obstacleAt = function(pos, size) {
  var xStart = Math.floor(pos.x);
  var xEnd = Math.ceil(pos.x + size.x);
  var yStart = Math.floor(pos.y);
  var yEnd = Math.ceil(pos.y + size.y);

  if (xStart < 0 || xEnd > this.width || yStart < 0)
    return "wall";
  if (yEnd > this.height)
    return "lava";
  if (yEnd > this.height)
    return "spike";
  if (yEnd > this.height)
    return "animal";
  for (var y = yStart; y < yEnd; y++) {
    for (var x = xStart; x < xEnd; x++) {
      var fieldType = this.grid[y][x];
      if (fieldType) return fieldType;
    }
  }
};

Level.prototype.actorAt = function(actor) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.actors.length; i++) {
    var other = this.actors[i];
    if (other != actor &&
        actor.pos.x + actor.size.x > other.pos.x &&
        actor.pos.x < other.pos.x + other.size.x &&
        actor.pos.y + actor.size.y > other.pos.y &&
        actor.pos.y < other.pos.y + other.size.y)
      return other;
  }
};

var maxStep = 0.05;

Level.prototype.animate = function(step, keys) {
  if (this.status !== null)
    this.finishDelay -= step;

  while (step > 0) {
    var thisStep = Math.min(step, maxStep);
    this.actors.forEach(function(actor) {
      actor.act(thisStep, this, keys);
    }, this);
    step -= thisStep;
  }
};

Lava.prototype.act = function(step, level) {
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(this.speed.times(step));
  if (!level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size))
    this.pos = newPos;
  else if (this.repeatPos)
    this.pos = this.repeatPos;
  else
    this.speed = this.speed.times(-1);
};
Spike.prototype.act = function(step, level) {
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(this.speed.times(step));
  if (!level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size))
    this.pos = newPos;
  else if (this.repeatPos)
    this.pos = this.repeatPos;
  else
    this.speed = this.speed.times(-1);
};

Animal.prototype.act = function(step, level) {
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(this.speed.times(step));
  if (!level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size))
    this.pos = newPos;
  else if (this.repeatPos)
    this.pos = this.repeatPos;
  else
    this.speed = this.speed.times(-1);
};

var wobbleSpeed = 8, wobbleDist = 0.07;

Coin.prototype.act = function(step) {
  this.wobble += step * wobbleSpeed;
  var wobblePos = Math.sin(this.wobble) * wobbleDist;
  this.pos = this.basePos.plus(new Vector(0, wobblePos));
};
Chest.prototype.act = function(step) {
  this.wobble += step * wobbleSpeed;
  var wobblePos = Math.sin(this.wobble) * wobbleDist;
  this.pos = this.basePos.plus(new Vector(0, wobblePos));
};
var playerXSpeed = 7;

Player.prototype.moveX = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.speed.x = 0;
  if (keys.left) this.speed.x -= playerXSpeed;
  if (keys.right) this.speed.x += playerXSpeed;

  var motion = new Vector(this.speed.x * step, 0);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);
  if (obstacle)
    level.playerTouched(obstacle);
  else
    this.pos = newPos;
};

var playerYHeight = 7;

Player.prototype.moveY = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.speed.y = 0;
  if (keys.up) this.speed.y -= playerYHeight;
  if (keys.down) this.speed.y += playerYHeight;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);
  if (obstacle) 
    level.playerTouched(obstacle);
  else
    this.pos = newPos;
};

Player.prototype.act = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.moveX(step, level, keys);
  this.moveY(step, level, keys);

  var otherActor = level.actorAt(this);
  if (otherActor)
    level.playerTouched(otherActor.type, otherActor);

  // Losing animation
  if (level.status == "lost") {
    this.pos.y += step;
    this.size.y -= step;
  }
};


Level.prototype.playerTouched = function(type, actor) {
  if (type == "animal" && this.status === null) {
    this.status = "lost";
    this.finishDelay = 1;
  } if (type == "lava" && this.status === null) {
    this.status = "lost";
    this.finishDelay = 1;
  } if (type == "spike" && this.status === null) {
    this.status = "lost";
    this.finishDelay = 1;
  }
   else if (type == "coin" ) {
    this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
      return other != actor;
    });
    if (!this.actors.some(function(actor) {
      return actor.type == "coin";
    })) {
      this.status = "won";
      this.finishDelay = 1;
    }
  }
    else if (type == "chest" ) {
    this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
      return other != actor;
    });
    if (!this.actors.some(function(actor) {
      return actor.type == "chest";
    })) {
      this.status = "won";
      this.finishDelay = 1;
    }
  }
};

var arrowCodes = {37: "left", 38: "up", 39: "right",40: "down" };

function trackKeys(codes) {
  var pressed = Object.create(null);
  function handler(event) {
    if (codes.hasOwnProperty(event.keyCode)) {
      var down = event.type == "keydown";
      pressed[codes[event.keyCode]] = down;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  addEventListener("keydown", handler);
  addEventListener("keyup", handler);
  return pressed;
}

function runAnimation(frameFunc) {
  var lastTime = null;
  function frame(time) {
    var stop = false;
    if (lastTime !== null) {
      var timeStep = Math.min(time - lastTime, 100) / 1000;                                                                 
stop = frameFunc(timeStep) === false;
        }
    lastTime = time;
    if (!stop)
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

var arrows = trackKeys(arrowCodes);



function runLevel(level, Display, andThen) {
  var display = new Display(document.body, level);
  runAnimation(function(step) {
    level.animate(step, arrows);
    display.drawFrame(step);
    if (level.isFinished()) {
      display.clear();
      if (andThen)
        andThen(level.status);
      return false;
    }
  });
    }



var lives = 3;

function runGame(plans, Display) {

  function startLevel(n) {
    runLevel(new Level(plans[n]), Display, function(status) {
      if (status == "lost") {
      lives--;
      if (lives === 0) {
      console.log("Game Over");
      alert("Game Over");
      }
      else
        startLevel(n);
        }
      else if (n < plans.length - 1)
        startLevel(n + 1);
      else
        console.log("You win!");
    });
  }
  startLevel(0);
};
```

Comment: If the enemy needs to find its way around obstacles and the board is small, you can find all-pairs-shortest-paths with Dijkstra’s algorithm.  In more complicated situations, the usual search algorithm is A*.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please be more specific on what the issues are with your current code. Meanwhile: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also consider asking this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can do some pathfinding from the monster to the player to follow the player. The easiest way is with conditions like this  `if (xPlayerPos > xMonsterPos && mapPosition != lava/spike/...) xMonster = xMonster + 1;`, the best way is backtracking to find all the possible paths, then find which one is the smallest and take it.

Comment: @AxelLaviellei have tried to be as specific as possible but am not really sure how to use this. i know my way around it but dont understand how to implement what you are saying. please help

Comment: Your player have a turn to play. Do the same for the AI.
During the AI turn, find a path to the human player using Pathfinding, Backtracking ect. (I let you search a bit about pathfinding and backtracking, there is a lot of algorithms online about them).
Once you have found the path, you know where to move, so move to the next cell your AI. On next turn, recalculate the path and re move. ect..